# Is there any problem in this code? (Python crawling)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know why there is an error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

This URL is a Korean question website.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.algotank.com/bbs/board.php?bo_table=algotank&wr_id=16"

source = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
AnsInput = soup.find_all("input",{"name":"AnsInput"})['answer']

print(AnsInput)
```

Comment: You haven't included your stack trace, but `find_all` returns a list, not a dictionary. You would need to use an integer index to get an element, then access `"answer"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BeautifulSoup's `find_all` will return a list, rather than a dictionary, so needs to be indexed using an integer if you want a specific element, e.g.

```
AnsInput = soup.find_all("input",{"name":"AnsInput"})[0]['answer']
```